# How to time batch file execution using timethis.exe?

Tags: time

While `timethis.exe` works fine for almost every application, it seems to fail for `.bat` files:

```
C:\test>timethis test.bat

TimeThis :  Command Line :  test.bat
TimeThis :    Start Time :  Fri Feb 26 19:46:30 2010

'test.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

TimeThis :  Command Line :  test.bat
TimeThis :    Start Time :  Fri Feb 26 19:46:30 2010
TimeThis :      End Time :  Fri Feb 26 19:46:30 2010
TimeThis :  Elapsed Time :  00:00:00.070
```

While executing it on a regular command line is fine, `timethis.exe` fails for it. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the start command:

`timethis "start test.bat"`

**EDIT:** Actually now I'm not sure if this will work. It didn't seem to give any time for my batch file.

After further tests I realized that: `timethis test.bat` works just fine for me. Maybe you need a different version of timethis or your test.bat file is not in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Running a .BAT file works fine for me, but if it doesn't work for you then try this:

```
    TIMETHIS CMD.EXE /C test.bat
```

The `TIMETHIS` tool is available for [download from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=3087).

It seems to work fine on Windows 7 as well.